# Can any one tell how to copy data of GridView into DataTable in ASP.NET in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, datatable

in my project I need to copy all the rows of GridView into a DataTable. Can any one tell this can be done in C# ASP.NET

Comment: Is this after the grid has been edited?

Comment: I have taken data in GridView for a database query now i need all these data to be saved in datatable

Answer (score 1):

You can use its `DataSource` property

```
 DataTable myDataTable = myGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
```